# Execute a Application On The Server Using PHP(With safe_mode enabled)

Tags: php, file-io, server-side

I have an application on my server that is called `leaf.exe`, that haves two arguments needed to run, they are: `inputfile` and `outputfile`, that will be like this example:

```
pnote.exe input.pnt output.txt
```

The executable is at `exec/`, inputfile is at `upload/` and outputfile is on `compiled/`. But I need that a PHP could run the application like that, then I want to know:

- How could I do this on a server that have `exec()` disabled and I can't turn it on, because I don't have privileges to do it?
- How could I `echo` the output of the program?

Comment: Having exec() disabled really changes things. That says the sysadmin purposely wants to prevent you from doing this.

Answer (score 3):

The exec function is probably what you're looking for: [PHP: exec - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Answer (score 2):

There are a fair amount of ways to do this. It partly depends on how your executables act and what they return. Have a look at [System Program Execution](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php). Hober suggests [`exec()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), and that may be right. Another possibility may be [`passthru()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)

Comment: Yeah, `passthru()` may be the real answer. As the `exec()` documentation reads: "If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function."